# Secure web form for accepting bank routing and account numbers

Tags: php, email, encryption, ssl

We have a website where we need to obtain our customers routing and bank acct #'s who want to sign up for monthly ACH withdrawals.  I was wondering the best way to achieve that. I thought about first making the form an SSL/https link and forcing it with .htaccess modrewrite.  Currently we are emailed the results of any information submitted to the site web forms. My next concern is the email sent from the server encrypted if you use smtp  TLS etc?  In other words what is the best may to transmit the data from the server back to our email securely.  Or is using email to transmit the data a bad idea altogether.  Any help/reccomendations is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I would like to add that we are not actually performing the ach.  We are just getting the information and passing it on to the vendor to perform the ach.  Currently it is a written and signed form they fax.  We can continue this process.  I was just looking to automate this portion only.  However, it sounds best to just outsource even this piece?

Comment: There's probably a standard for the storage of these numbers, but I don't know of it. I would adhere to the [PCI Standard for Credit Cards](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php).

Comment: It's a bad idea to send this sort of thing by email, even if it's encrypted in transit - since some email accounts are shared, or are used on insecure workstations.

Comment: I would like to add that we are not actually performing the ach.  We are just getting the information and passing it on to the vendor to perform the ach.  Currently it is a written and signed form they fax.  We can continue this process.  I was just looking to automate this portion only.  However, it sounds best to just outsource even this piece?

Comment: @halfer stands for "automated clearing house"  it is an electronic network that will allow for deductions from one bank account to another.  If I recall i think it is similar to a Giro payment in European banks.

Comment: One learns something new every day! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve this is to outsource it to a financial institution which is already compliant with PCI DSS rules, local financial regulations, and the like.

I'll repeat that: **do not do it yourself**. Have someone else who knows what's up do it for you.

There are services that provide this: Amazon Payments, Dwolla... Why would you need to handle the actual account numbers? What you care about is that the cash gets to you, not its exact origin.

And **NO, EMAIL IS NOT SECURE**. Unless you're encrypting it, and if you had to ask the question, you're not. **NEVER** send confidential information in a plain email. (Caveat for experts: a TLS-secured SMTP session with no intermediate relays connecting to a DNSSEC-provided IP address is reasonably secure. It's doubtful that your average Joe would implement this properly, however).

Comment: I deal with PCI Compliance every day and I couldn't have said it better than @Borealid.  Don't take the risk!!

Comment: I think it is okay to handle these things if (a) you are very careful and use encryption etc. as appropriate **and** (b) you are not storing them in your database. If you fail either of these tests, take Borealid's advice. +1

Comment: @halfer: I daresay that the bottom line is that *if* you are asking on SO then you probably aren't enough of an expert.

Comment: @Borealid I just want to say that I have a general understanding of PCI compliance and we have websites that use Ecommerce shopping carts and we use amazon payments, paypal, auth.net and ARB where we are not storing any information on our servers etc.  That said, in attempting to automate the fax portion of our signup form for ACH, you are correct in it does bring up the same sort of security issues.  Thx.